# I get the error "no mapping between user and security ids was done" when I try to deploy a cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas

When I try to deploy my SQL Server Analysis Services project to the server, I get the error message `No mapping between user and security ids was done`. I don't get where this is coming from!

I've checked the user credentials on the Data Source. I've previously deployed projects to the same server with the same credentials with no problems.

When I google this problem, I get a lot of hits for things to do with Active Directory, but nothing that directly links to SSAS. Where does this error spring from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when there are users defined in a role that are either not known to the server (i.e. a local account on the machine the project was designed on) or no longer available in the Active Directory. To solve this:

- Open the cube in BIDS / Visual Studio
- Go to the Roles node in the Solution Explorer
- Per role, go to the tab "memberships"
- Per member defined, check to see if that member still exists in the AD.

In my experience, it's advisable not to use local users in Roles, nor personal accounts. Instead, grant the rights to a role to a group, then add and remove users to that group in the Active Directory as needed.

Comment: Install the free BI Developer Extensions and run the Roles Report. It will look role members up in AD and show which ones don't exist. https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/RolesReport/